# Importing Github RAML folder fails with "Imported folder contains multiple Root of the RAML 0.8 Specs."

Tags: postman, raml

I'm starting to look at a tool that uses RAML.  I noticed the following old blog post that demonstrates importing RAML folders into Postman: https://blog.postman.com/supporting-raml-folders-in-postman/ .  This demonstrates using a specific RAML repository, https://github.com/raml-apis/GitHub .

When I attempt this, it fails with this error message:

> Error while importing RAML 0.8: Imported folder contains multiple Root of the RAML 0.8 Specs.

I'm only beginning to explore RAML, so this might be a simple problem.

Comment: Which version of the app are you using? Blog post is also 5 years old now and the platform has changed a little bit 

Comment: I keep Postman very much up to date. I just updated it today, to v7.35.0.

Comment: I even tried importing just the "api.raml" file, but that fails with "Import Failed. There was an unexpected error. Please try again."